Converting a C# string to a hex representation of its UTF8-encoded characters
I have a string in C# which could contain any set of Unicode characters and I want to convert it into a hex representation of the UTF8 encoding of that string with a space between each Unicode character, so for instance the string "$£€" would be converted to an output string of "24 C2A3 E282AC F0908D88".  I can't see how to do this, though.  Because strings in C# are UTF16 I can't just say foreach (char entry in myString) { ... } because a Unicode glyph can be represented by either 1 or 2 chars, as in the case for the last glyph in my example above.
I feel like I need to end up with a byte[][] which represents the list of characters, each represented as a list of UTF8-encoded bytes that determine the character.  I could then convert those bytes to their hex representation, with spaces between the Unicode characters.
How could I achieve the desired output?

How exactly are you defining "unicode character"? Is that an extended grapheme cluster (the normally-agreed-upon definition of what a single editable symbol is), or a unicode codepoint, or something else?

(For a unicode codepoint, look at the Rune class. For EGCs, look at StringInfo)

It seems like StringInfo would give me a TextElementEnumerator whose GetTextElement method would allow me to deal with the string on a per-Unicode-character basis; but even then, how would I convert those characters to their equivalent UTF8 bytes, especially if it's a UTF16 character taking up 3 or 4 bytes (in which case the returned string.Length would be 2)?

Assuming by "unicode character" you do mean EGCs, then: TextElementEnumerator gives you a list of substrings. Each substring contains the set of codepoints which make up that EGC. If you want to convert one of those substrings to UTF-8 bytes, then use Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes

See the second part of my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66064611/1086121 for a discussion on how codepoints combine to form EGCs, using emoji as an example

You can minimize your intermediate memory allocations by making use of the Rune struct, and by using stackalloc'ed intermediate buffers, like so:
public static partial class TextHelper
{
    public static string ToUtf8HexValues(this string s)
    {
        Span<byte> runeByteSpan = stackalloc byte[4]; // rune.EncodeToUtf8() can be up to 4 bytes as shown in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Text/Rune.cs#L1060
        Span<char> charSpan = stackalloc char[2]; // Greater than or equal to the max number of hex chars in a byte value, which is 2.
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var rune in s.EnumerateRunes())
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0)
                sb.Append(' ');
            for (int i = 0, length = rune.EncodeToUtf8(runeByteSpan); i < length; i++)
                if (runeByteSpan[i].TryFormat(charSpan, out var n, "X"))
                    sb.Append(charSpan.Slice(0, n));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

Notes:

Rune was introduced in .NET Core 3.  This struct:

Represents a Unicode scalar value ([ U+0000..U+D7FF ], inclusive; or [ U+E000..U+10FFFF ], inclusive).


Byte.TryFormat(Span<Char>, Int32, ReadOnlySpan<Char>, IFormatProvider) was introduced in .NET Core 2.1 and allows a Byte to be formatted to a fixed-length Span<char> without a string allocation.


Demo fiddle #1 here.
If you only want a space to be inserted between grapheme clusters such as Ĥ, then (starting with .NET 6) you can use StringInfo.GetNextTextElementLength(ReadOnlySpan<Char>) to enumerate through a string as in chunks that cluster combining characters together:
public static partial class TextHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<ReadOnlyMemory<char>> TextElements(this string s) => (s ?? "").AsMemory().TextElements();

    public static IEnumerable<ReadOnlyMemory<char>> TextElements(this ReadOnlyMemory<char> s)
    {
        for (int index = 0, length = StringInfo.GetNextTextElementLength(s.Span); 
             length > 0; 
             index += length, length = StringInfo.GetNextTextElementLength(s.Span.Slice(index)))
            yield return s.Slice(index, length);
    }   
    
    public static string ToUtf8GraphemeHexValues(this string s)
    {
        Span<byte> runeByteSpan = stackalloc byte[4]; // rune.EncodeToUtf8() can be up to 4 bytes as shown in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Text/Rune.cs#L1060
        Span<char> charSpan = stackalloc char[2]; // Greater than or equal to the max number of hex chars in a byte value, which is 2.
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var chunk in s.TextElements())
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0)
                sb.Append(' ');
            foreach (var rune in chunk.Span.EnumerateRunes())
                for (int i = 0, length = rune.EncodeToUtf8(runeByteSpan); i < length; i++)
                    if (runeByteSpan[i].TryFormat(charSpan, out var n, "X"))
                        sb.Append(charSpan.Slice(0, n));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

Notes:

In earlier versions you can use StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(String), however using this method will result in allocating a string for each grapheme cluster,

Demo fiddle #2 here.

canton7 said that Rune doesn't include support for extended grapheme clusters (I don't claim to be familiar with what those are)...

Again it comes down to what you define as a "Unicode character". If you mean a codepoint, then a Rune is what you want

@Jez - but that's not what you asked for. In your question you asked for "a space between each Unicode character".  Do you want that, or do you want a space only between clusters?

@Jez - OK, I added a version that only inserts a space between grapheme clusters.

@dbc For span, how come it's not a byte[6]?  The result I get from Encoding.UTF8.GetMaxByteCount(1) is 6.  Also, the max number of hex characters in a byte value is 2 so why isn't charSpan a char[2]?

@Jez - No particularly strong reason.  At some point I fell into the habit of making small buffers 8-byte aligned.  Probably I'm just showing my age here. I can change it if you like.

Feels better to me as a perfectionist.  :-)  It worked when I changed it to 6 and 2, just wanted to check I wasn't overlooking something.

@Jez - on second thought, there's a small bug here: a Rune can represent up to 2 Unicode characters, so I needed to use the value of Encoding.UTF8.GetMaxByteCount(2) as the buffer size.  Fixed.

@dbc The odd thing is that for the character  which is a 2 char rune, the value of 6 worked fine.  By the way your comment says 9, not 12 ;-)

@Jez - My recollection is that Encoding.UTF8.GetMaxByteCount(2) returns larger that one would expect because of the possibility that fallbacks for chars that can't be encoded might get inserted.  (NB: encoding is potentially lossy.)

@Jez - looking at the reference source, Rune.TryEncodeToUtf8(Rune value, Span<byte> destination, out int bytesWritten) doesn't use fallbacks or check for validity, so the max number of characters that might get written is 4.  Feel free to change that.

Rune only ever represents a single Unicode codepoint - there's no such thing as a "2 char rune". Some codepoints require 2 UTF-16 code units (i.e. two 2-byte chars) to represent, but that's a quirk of UTF-16 encoding, and encoding 149,878 different code points using units 2 bytes wide. UTF-8 takes a maximum of 4 bytes to encode any codepoint, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding

@canton7 That seems like a distinction without a difference.  If it takes 4 bytes to encode it's a "2 char rune", ie. it takes 2 C# char values to represent as a char is 16 bits.

@Jez Runes represent Unicode codepoints. There are 1,114,112 different codepoints, representing things like letters, characters, emoji, etc. There are a number of different standards for representing codepoints using bytes. UTF-16 uses either 2 or 4 bytes to represent each codepoint, UTF-32 always uses 4, UTF-8 uses 1-4. So the encoding, the number of bytes, is a different level of abstraction to the concept of a Codepoint (which is just a number). So to say a "4-byte codepoint/Rune" makes no sense without referring to encoding. When using UTF-32, all codepoints take 4 bytes to encode!
